# Why isn't my jQuery working locally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, attr, jsfiddle

I use the following code on jsfiddle.net and the live preview works. Run my own local copy, and nothing...

Checkboxes should change on radiobutton click.

**jsfiddle preview: http://jsfiddle.net/XqFDN/**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script>
        jQuery('#3day').click(function () {
            jQuery('#mon , #tue , #wed').attr('checked', true);
        });
        jQuery('#2day , #1day').click(function () {
            jQuery('#mon , #tue , #wed').attr('checked', false);
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="passes" value="3day" id="3day" />3-Day
        <input type="radio" name="passes" value="2day" id="2day" />2-Day
        <input type="radio" name="passes" value="1day" id="1day" />1-Day
        <br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="mon" value="mon" id="mon" />Mon
        <input type="checkbox" name="tue" value="tue" id="tue" />Tue
        <input type="checkbox" name="wed" value="wed" id="wed" />Wed
        <br />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Under "choose framework" in your fiddle, you've selected "no wrap (body)". The code you've pasted is equivalent of the option "no wrap (head)".

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not. // And you should use `.prop('checked', true_or_false)` instead of `attr`

Comment: Didn't even occur to me to use .prop as .attr worked fine - thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementByID` not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element).

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I put codes from jsfiddle.net into my website?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4936870/1048572)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to wrap your jQuery code in a document ready handler. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() { // alternative: $(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#3day').click(function () {
            jQuery('#mon , #tue , #wed').attr('checked', true);
        });
        jQuery('#2day , #1day').click(function () {
            jQuery('#mon , #tue , #wed').attr('checked', false);
        });
    });
</script>
```

This enclosure ensures that the code within it is run when the DOM has been loaded. Currently, your code is trying to attach `click` events to elements which do not yet exist.

Comment: Correct. And the pasted fiddle works, not because it's executed at DOMReady, but because it's executed at the bottom of BODY.

Comment: Thank you - a simple fix I shall utlise in all my coding.