# JQuery works in JS fiddle, but not on my website?

Tags: jquery, class, selector, jsfiddle

All right, something REALLY frustrating and weird is going on. I have JQuery installed on my server, and I know it's imported correctly because when I run a simple...

`$(function() { alert('hello') });`

It alerts "hello." However, when I try to use a css selector...

`$(".image").css("border","3px solid red");`

It does not work! Yes, I'm 100% sure there is something with that class name in the file. Here's the real kicker, when I COPY PASTED my code into a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfLt7/) it worked just fine. What gives?!

Comment: are you sure that there is no conflicts of jquery?

Comment: Where did you put your code? In a DOM ready? Window load? bottom of the page? In narnia? Im pretty sure it work on the fiddle because it put it in a window load by default.

Comment: any error in the browser console

Comment: Are you loading jQuery on your page at your site? Does it load? You need something like `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>` in the head of your page

Comment: check console for error

Comment: I'm using `<script src="../javascript/jquery.js"></script>` to import my code, its my understanding that with hTML5 you do not have to add `type="text/javascript"` as Javascript is the default code. I have redownloaded the JQuery file three times, it's being imported inside the two `<head>` tags, where its supposed to go. I've tried running the script inside the body tag, in the head tag, I've tried running it from an external Javascript file, still nothing.

Comment: Need to see "your" code, in addition to the jsfiddle, to help you debug (notice how many answers/comments are guessing to some degree?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your jsFiddle is set for `onload` in the upper left of the jsFiddle window.  If you set it to "No Wrap - in Head" which simulates code in the `<head>` tag, then your jsFiddle no longer works.

The `onload` setting means that jsFiddle doesn't run your javascript until the page has been loaded.

In your real page, you are probably running the javascript too soon before the page has been loaded.

You can either fix that by putting your javascript in it's own `.ready()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".image").css("border","3px solid red");
});
```

---

Or, you can make sure the javascript isn't loaded/run until right before the `</body>` tag which is a simple way to make sure the content of your page is loaded before the script runs.

```
<body>
Your HTML content here

<script>
// your script here that runs after all of the DOM is parsed
$(".image").css("border","3px solid red");
</script>

</body>
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the/9899701#9899701) for more details on placing the `<script>` tag appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Have you test adding inside `$(document).ready(function(){});` ?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".image").css("border","3px solid red");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Uh, if `$(".image").css("border","3px solid red");` Does not work, then it cannot be used to test the readiness of the file. However, if I use `$(function() { alert('hello') });` inside, yes I do get the alert.

Comment: ^ I take that back. It worked. If that worked why can't I just put `    $(".image").css("border","3px solid red");`? That still does not work.

Comment: Does not work? pls see here...http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/mfLt7/2/

Answer (score -2):

```
if u have a internet connection following link useful for you 

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script> 

above link put inside a body or before write a script and please verify jquery js file.
```

Comment: This isn't the problem.