# How to include external jQuery file in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have make a small example in JSFiddle. It is correct, but now I want to put the content of that example in files in localhost in my computer. But I am having problems with including the `.js` file. It does not load. Please could you help me? What is the problem?

Here is my JSFiddle example: [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/orsina/n5m3bfen/)

Here is my `index.html` file in local host :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--This is the first html page of the website-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="This is a simple example">
<meta name="keywords" content="multiple, add, substract"> 
<title>Tirana</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="style2.css">
<link rel="icon" href="images/logo.png" type="image/png" sizes="40x35">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<textarea id="input" name="Input1" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="enter your input here">
number a =5
number b =7
sum = a+b 
</textarea>
<input type="button" value="test" />
<textarea id="output" name="Output1" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="output" readonly></textarea>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And I have use this to include the `.js` file:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="codejs.js"></script>
```

Here is my `codejs.js` file:

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function () {
    var result= "";
    var lines = $('#input').val().split('\n');

    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            result += lines[i];
            result += "\n";
    }

    $("#output").html(result);

});
```

Please could you help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: it's depend on your folder structure

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery works in JS fiddle, but not on my website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417326/jquery-works-in-js-fiddle-but-not-on-my-website)

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is managing dependencies of js files. There are many possible options for that like using `require` library.

With respect to your code, the simplest way to address the problem is move your code in `ready` block.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     // move your code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what Nikhil is doing or you can do this.

You are Missing

```
$(function(){  // DOM IS NOW READY

    /* YOUR CODE HERE */

});
```

[jQuery docs .ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Try it like this for your code.

```
$(function(){
$('input[type=button]').click(function () {
    var result= "";
    var lines = $('#input').val().split('\n');

    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            result += lines[i];
            result += "\n";
    }

    $("#output").html(result);

});
});
```