# removing first 14 characters from string, works on fiddle but not site

Tags: javascript, html

I have this fiddle I have been testing to remove the first 14 characters from a span on my website, I'm trying to remove "Published on:"

https://jsfiddle.net/tetzuro/3ym8jwcu/

For some reason it won't work on the page, which is https://www.homecarepulse.com/blog/

I'm not sure what I am missing from my code but here it is for reference

```js
$('.fusion-tb-published-date').text(function(_, txt) {
  return txt.slice(14);
});
```

```html
<div class="fusion-meta-tb fusion-meta-tb-1 floated" style="padding-bottom:15px;min-height:36px;font-size:16px;">
  <span class="fusion-tb-published-date">Published On: Jul 28, 2022</span><span class="fusion-meta-tb-sep"></span>
  <span class="fusion-tb-author">By
<span><a href="" rel="author">author</a></span></span>
  <span class="fusion-meta-tb-sep"></span>
  <span class="fusion-tb-published-read-time">23.8 min read</span>
  <span class="fusion-meta-tb-sep"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I put codes from jsfiddle.net into my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936870/how-do-i-put-codes-from-jsfiddle-net-into-my-website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error in the console

`Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`.

That means you are, most probably using it before the `$` is initialised or not initialising it at all.

The fastest solution for this is to replace `$` with `jQuery`:

```
jQuery('.fusion-tb-published-date').text(function (_,txt) {
    return txt.slice(14);
});
```

Comment: this also works as a alternative to the suggested above, nice!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't imported the jQuery library on the site! In the dev console, I can see that `$` isn't defined. Try importing the jQuery library from a CDN like so:

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: jquery is definitely being loaded `<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.homecarepulse.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0' id='jquery-core-js'></script>
`

Comment: This works! i didnt realize i needed to import the script with using $

Comment: given the fact that the OP is using WordPress, manually loading jQuery is redundant since WP already loads jQuery. It's just a matter of script prioritisation.

Comment: @CornelRaiu That's the way of the WordPress. It always loads jQuery. It rarely loads it when you think it will, though!

Comment: @MichaelW. agree. That's why properly setting dependencies is important