# Expanding DIV on mouseover / un-expands on mouseout

Tags: html, hover, mouseover, expand, contract

[I found this Q/A,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755381/looking-to-build-an-expand-on-hover-contract-on-blur-div)

But when I modify it for my usage as seen here http://jsfiddle.net/6PDEA/4/ the bottom-most div doesn't stay closed. Can anyone help?

**EDIT: 1st answer fixed the "expanded on load" issue, but not the bottom-most DIV**

---

**EDIT 2: Final working code: http://jsfiddle.net/6PDEA/5/**

**Fixed the bottom DIV issue. I just added another DIV below it with a blank graphic sized 785w x 30h.**

Comment: Could you please provide some of the modified code you are using, so we can see what could be the problem.

Comment: Link is in the question above, but here it is again: http://jsfiddle.net/6PDEA/4/

Comment: It may also be a good idea to use [hoverIntent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) with this technique.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is wrong :

It should not be

```
div#fp-cat {
   height: 30px;
   width: 785px;
}
```

but :

```
div.fp-cat {
   height: 30px;
   width: 785px;
}
```

Because fp-cat is a class shared by various divs...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my obvious mistake :)   That makes the DIV's start collapsed like they should be, but didn't fix the last one not starting collapsed and operating like it should :(